# Web development server for windows?

Tags: windows, web

Can anyone suggest a good web development stack for Windows? I've tried xampp, but I want to see what else is available; has anyone had any particular experience with any alternatives? I'm looking for something that will run PHP at the very least.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Really? 6.5 years after i asked? ;)

Comment: Yes. We close old questions that to not match the rules of the site anymore. Call it taking out old rubbish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no better development stack than the one that you intend on deploying to production.

I'm absolutely not kidding.

Make your DEV as close as possible to your PROD.  You could debate on the validity of going as far as the hardware stack, but you certainly should have the OS version / edition / service pack as well as the app stack.

Practice like you're going to perform.

Answer (score 0):

This lists out all the WAMP distributions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Most wamps such as XAMPP and WampServer are free, but are not geared for production deployment.  Some like WampDeveloper Pro are commercial and come with additional features.

Answer (score -2):

WAMP is great. It is slim and has all the bells of and whistles.
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/312846)

Comment: Um this was from 7 years ago... times may have changed... maybe your productivity is better spent on newer content.